# Finding difference between two tables in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables with exactly same schema. One is a week old and other is current. Let new record be new_data and the old be old_data. Both have a column called opportunity_id which is the primary key, sales stages(1,2,3,4..etc) and sales_values. Now in a week a sales stage may change for an opportunity or sales values of an opportunity may change. Even a new Opportunity_id may be added. I need all the data that has changed.

I am trying INNER_JOIN but that only works when opportunity_ids match.I need newly added opportunities also.

I am using MS Access, so please provide only sql solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is the **EXISTS** clause. It returns rows that match on criteria (or doesn't match). Your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   new_data AS n 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   old_data AS o 
                   WHERE  n.opportunity_id = o.opportunity_id 
                          AND n.sales_stages = o.sales_stages 
                          AND n.sales_values = o.sales_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead (providing the table on the left is New_Data)

```
SELECT n.opportunity_id, n.sales_stage, n.sales_values, [o].sales_stage, [o].sales_values
FROM new_data AS n LEFT JOIN old_data AS o 
  ON n.opportunity_id = [o].opportunity_id
WHERE (((n.sales_stage)<>[o].[sales_stage])) 
   OR (((n.sales_values)<>[o].[sales_values])) 
   OR ((([o].opportunity_id) Is Null));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you truly need **ALL** changes, there's one more case to consider.

What about deleted keys? Meaning keys that exist in `old_data` and not in `new_data`. To get these, use the same general approach (in my limited experience OUTER JOIN seems to perform better in Access):

```
SELECT [o].opportunity_id
FROM new_data AS n RIGHT JOIN old_data AS o 
  ON n.opportunity_id = [o].opportunity_id
WHERE ((([o].opportunity_id) Is Not Null))
  AND ((([n].opportunity_id) Is Null));
```